# Failing to Connect to Ejabberd Server using react-native-xmpp

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm trying to create a basic chat app using react-native-xmpp and Ejabberd, but I'm getting a certificate error. Here is the full console output:

```
Pressed
[Fri Aug 21 2020 04:40:01.140]  LOG      react-native-xmpp: Message: "Testing..." being sent to user: user@ec2-3-14-27-95.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

[Fri Aug 21 2020 04:40:01.360]  LOG      react-native-xmpp: Error: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Hostname verification of certificate failed. Certificate does not authenticate ec2-3-14-27-95.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

[Fri Aug 21 2020 04:40:01.366]  LOG      react-native-xmpp: Disconnected, error: Hostname verification of certificate failed. Certificate does not authenticate ec2-3-14-27-95.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

I can log onto the Ejabberd web admin panel no problem and the server launches with no issues, but it doesn't seem to like accepting XMPP connections. Here is my client code:

```js
var XMPP = require('react-native-xmpp');

class App extends Component {

  test() {
    console.log('Pressed');
    var user = 'admin@ec2-3-14-27-95.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com';
    var password = 'password';

    var to = 'user@ec2-3-14-27-95.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com';

    XMPP.trustHosts(['ec2-3-14-27-95.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com']);
    XMPP.connect(user, password);
    XMPP.message('Testing...', to);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.center}>
        <Button title="Button" onPress={this.test} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The code is hideous, but right now I just want to make sure I can establish and maintain a connection.

EDIT:

Error dialog from Gajim:

[image]

Certificate details from Gajim:

[image]

ejabberd.yml:

```yaml
###
###'           ejabberd configuration file
###
### The parameters used in this configuration file are explained at
###
###       https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration
###
### The configuration file is written in YAML.
### *******************************************************
### *******           !!! WARNING !!!               *******
### *******     YAML IS INDENTATION SENSITIVE       *******
### ******* MAKE SURE YOU INDENT SECTIONS CORRECTLY *******
### *******************************************************
### Refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML for the brief description.
###

hosts:
  - "ec2-3-14-27-95.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com"

loglevel: 4
log_rotate_size: 10485760
log_rotate_date: ""
log_rotate_count: 1
log_rate_limit: 100

certfiles:
  - "/opt/ejabberd/conf/server.pem"
##  - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/fullchain.pem"
##  - "/etc/letsencrypt/live/localhost/privkey.pem"

ca_file: "/opt/ejabberd/conf/cacert.pem"

listen:
  -
    port: 5222
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_c2s
    max_stanza_size: 262144
    shaper: c2s_shaper
    access: c2s
    starttls_required: true
  -
    port: 5269
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_s2s_in
    max_stanza_size: 524288
  -
    port: 5443
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    tls: true
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
      "/api": mod_http_api
      "/bosh": mod_bosh
      "/captcha": ejabberd_captcha
      "/upload": mod_http_upload
      "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
      "/oauth": ejabberd_oauth
  -
    port: 5280
    ip: "::"
    module: ejabberd_http
    request_handlers:
      "/admin": ejabberd_web_admin
  -
    port: 1883
    ip: "::"
    module: mod_mqtt
    backlog: 1000

s2s_use_starttls: optional

acl:
  local:
    user_regexp: ""
  loopback:
    ip:
      - 127.0.0.0/8
      - ::1/128
      - ::FFFF:127.0.0.1/128
  admin:
    user:
      - "admin@ec2-3-14-27-95.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com"

access_rules:
  local:
    allow: local
  c2s:
    deny: blocked
    allow: all
  announce:
    allow: admin
  configure:
    allow: admin
  muc_create:
    allow: local
  pubsub_createnode:
    allow: local
  trusted_network:
    allow: loopback

api_permissions:
  "console commands":
    from:
      - ejabberd_ctl
    who: all
    what: "*"
  "admin access":
    who:
      access:
        allow:
          acl: loopback
          acl: admin
      oauth:
        scope: "ejabberd:admin"
        access:
          allow:
            acl: loopback
            acl: admin
    what:
      - "*"
      - "!stop"
      - "!start"
  "public commands":
    who:
      ip: 127.0.0.1/8
    what:
      - status
      - connected_users_number

shaper:
  normal: 1000
  fast: 50000

shaper_rules:
  max_user_sessions: 10
  max_user_offline_messages:
    5000: admin
    100: all
  c2s_shaper:
    none: admin
    normal: all
  s2s_shaper: fast

max_fsm_queue: 10000

acme:
   contact: "mailto:admin@ec2-3-14-27-95.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com"
   ca_url: "https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org"

modules:
  mod_adhoc: {}
  mod_admin_extra: {}
  mod_announce:
    access: announce
  mod_avatar: {}
  mod_blocking: {}
  mod_bosh: {}
  mod_caps: {}
  mod_carboncopy: {}
  mod_client_state: {}
  mod_configure: {}
  mod_disco: {}
  mod_fail2ban: {}
  mod_http_api: {}
  mod_http_upload:
    put_url: https://@HOST@:5443/upload
  mod_last: {}
  mod_mam:
    ## Mnesia is limited to 2GB, better to use an SQL backend
    ## For small servers SQLite is a good fit and is very easy
    ## to configure. Uncomment this when you have SQL configured:
    ## db_type: sql
    assume_mam_usage: true
    default: never
  mod_mqtt: {}
  mod_muc:
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
    access_mam:
      - allow
    default_room_options:
      allow_subscription: true  # enable MucSub
      mam: false
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  mod_privacy: {}
  mod_private: {}
  mod_proxy65:
    access: local
    max_connections: 5
  mod_pubsub:
    access_createnode: pubsub_createnode
    plugins:
      - flat
      - pep
    force_node_config:
      ## Avoid buggy clients to make their bookmarks public
      storage:bookmarks:
        access_model: whitelist
  mod_push: {}
  mod_push_keepalive: {}
  mod_register:
    ## Only accept registration requests from the "trusted"
    ## network (see access_rules section above).
    ## Think twice before enabling registration from any
    ## address. See the Jabber SPAM Manifesto for details:
    ## https://github.com/ge0rg/jabber-spam-fighting-manifesto
    ip_access: trusted_network
  mod_roster:
    versioning: true
  mod_s2s_dialback: {}
  mod_shared_roster: {}
  mod_stream_mgmt:
    resend_on_timeout: if_offline
  mod_vcard: {}
  mod_vcard_xupdate: {}
  mod_version:
    show_os: false

### Local Variables:
### mode: yaml
### End:
### vim: set filetype=yaml tabstop=8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still using the example certificate provided by the ejabberd installer. It is self-signed, and has no validity, so the error message is to be expected.

If you want that error to go away, either don't use encryption, or better: obtain a certificate signed by a certification authority.

Comment: Ah thanks! I disabled encryption on the server, and I also had to manually disable encryption on the client following this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49429661/unable-to-connect-with-openfire-using-react-native-xmpp. My issue is fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

> I can log onto the Ejabberd web admin panel no problem

Using HTTP or HTTPS? Check if your web browser reports any problem or doubt about the certificate.

> but it doesn't seem to like accepting XMPP connections.

Well, in my understaning, it seems your client rejects the certificate provided by ejabberd because the certificate's declared host doesn't match the host that it is serving.

You can try to login with well known Jabber/XMPP clients, like Gajim or Psi. Maybe those tests give you some more light about the problem.

Comment: I'm using HTTP. I guess that would explain the lack of a security error. I installed Gajim and I'm also getting certificate errors. I'll update the question to include what Gajim is telling me.